# Analytic proof of quadratic reciprocity

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, quadratic-residues

Is there any proof of quadratic reciprocity that is more analytic than those described on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity)?

Comment: Yes, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1420/whats-the-best-proof-of-quadratic-reciprocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Fourier-analytic proof of quadratic reciprocity, see section $3$ of http://www.math.upenn.edu/~shanshand/research/08srthesis.pdf.